# Will C++ always prefer an rvalue reference conversion operator over const lvalue reference when possible?

Tags: c++, c++11

When writing conversion operators, if I provide both a conversion to `const T&` and `T&&`, will C++ always prefer the rvalue operator when possible?  This seems to be true in this small test:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>

struct holds {
  operator       int&&()      { printf("moving!\n");  return std::move(i); }
  operator const int&() const { printf("copying!\n"); return i;            }

private:
  int i = 0;
};


int main() {
  holds h;
  int val = h;
}
```

prints:

```
 ╰─▸ ./test
moving!
```

But perhaps someone that speaks spec-ese better than I can verify?

Comment: You should ref-qualify your `operator int&&()`: `operator int&&() && { ... }`

Comment: I would if I had a compiler that supported ref qualifiers...

Comment: @SeanMcAllister Don't tell me you're again using Intel 13.

Comment: @Walter I am indeed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no such preference.

Your example is actually showing preference for a non-const member function over a const one when called on a non-const object.

Comment: I see, so if my T& operator was non-const as well, it could choose to call either?

Comment: It would be ambiguous.

Comment: @T.C. Adding that to your answer would help.

Answer (score 2):

So I don't have the energy and time to bury myself in the standard for this one. I am sure someone will.

However I want to point out your assumption is wrong. And you are missing a crucial information: one operator is `const`, one is not and it turns out this is the deciding factor in your case not `&&` vs `const &`. Let's see:

## Both methods mutable, mutable object:

```
operator       int&&();
operator const int&() ;
```

```
holds h;
int val = h; // compile error
```

Gives the error:

> conversion from 'holds' to 'int' is ambiguous

So you see both conversion operators are *equal* and none is preferred so there is an ambiguity.

### Both methods mutable, const object:

```
operator       int&&();
operator const int&() ;
```

```
const holds h;
int val = h;   // error no viable method
```

Well, this is an easy and non-interesting one: no mutable method can be called on a const object

### `&&` mutable, `const&` const, object mutable

```
operator       int&&();
operator const int&() const;
```

```
holds h;
int val = h; // calls holds::operator int&&()
```

Now the mutable method is preferred because the object is mutable

### `&&` mutable, `const&` const, object const

```
operator       int&&();
operator const int&() const;
```

```
const holds h;
int val = h;   // calls  holds::operator int const&() const
```

Now the `const` method is the only choice as a mutable method cannot be called on a const object.

Comment: What happens if the conversion to `int&&` is also ref qualified and you `std::move(h)`? Is it still ambiguous?

Comment: @Walter what do you mean **also** ref qualified? No operator in the example is ref qualified. What you do in the body of the function be it `std::move` or anything else has absolutely no impact on overload resolution.

Comment: I meant `operator int&&() &&;`